# How to check the URL's structure using PHP preg_match?

Tags: php, url, preg-match

All my site's URLs have the following structure:

*https://www.example.com/section/item*

where *section* is a word and *item* is a number.

So, possible URLs are:

*https://www.example.com*

*https://www.example.com/section*

*https://www.example.com/section/item*

By .htaccess, all requests go to *index.php* (route).

I want to show a 404 error message if user types:

*https://www.example.com/section/item/somethingelse*

In order to check the URL's structure, how can I change the pattern properly in the following function?

```
function isValidURL($url) {
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Makes more sense in my head that you'd test the URI path against valid routes (and hand over to relevant place) and then default to 404 if nothing is found. isValidUrl doesn't seem to make sense if they've already got this far?

Comment: @Jonnix How can I "test the URI path against valid routes"? Would you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If section is a word (and can not contain digits), and item is a number, you could match word characters except digits using `[^\W\d]+` and `\d+` to match 1+ digits.

As in the example data there are optional parts, you could replace `(/.*)?$` with `(?:/[^\W\d]+(?:/\d+)?)?$`.

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `/[^\W\d]+` For section, match 1+ times a word char except a digit
  - `(?:/\d+)?` For item, optionally match `/` and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

If section can be a word which can also consists of only digits, you could also use `\w+`

The pattern might look like

```
^https?://[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(?::[0-9]+)?(?:/[^\W\d]+(?:/\d+)?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGV9LO/1)

Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

Comment: This is very useful to me. Thanks a lot!